# Inria dataset train matlab error using neg file

Tags: matlab, dataset, computer-vision, svm

Hello i have INRIA dataset images of pedestrians and i want to load this data set to train it using svm am following this tutorial.
http://fr.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/digit-classification-using-hog-features.html

in the folder /train_64x128_H96 there is only the folder of positive images /pos
when i use this code in matlab it load the positive folder perfectly.

```
trainingPosSet = imageDatastore(posdir,   'IncludeSubfolders', true, 'LabelSource', 'foldernames');
```

with posdir='train_64x128_H96/pos';
my issue is with the /neg giving it's a **symbolic** link so when i try the same command with the /neg directory i have this error

> Error using imageDatastore (line 85)
> Input folders or files contain non-standard file extensions.
>
> Use FileExtensions Name-Value pair to include the non-standard file extensions.

i want to know how to load the negative dataset to train my svm Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following solution:
i copied the real '/neg' file and deleted the symbolic in the /train_64x128_H96 directory and i also delted all the .jpg files in '/neg' and only left .png files the command worked and the dataset is stored in matlab.
The question here what is the proper way to solve this problem.
I know this solution is very bad.